# SyntaxError: invalid syntax Counter

Tags: python

```
count = 0

for filename in glob.glob(directory + "/**/*", recursive=True):

    f = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    for line in f:
        match1 = re.findall(u"-", line)
        count+= len(match1)
        if count >= 1000:
            os.remove(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '../../filename')
        count = 0
```

Ошибка

```
  File "script_4_remove_gaps_vol2.py", line 15
    count = 0
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Что написано не так?

Comment: А что написано в предыдущей строке, в 14-й?

Comment: os.remove(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '../../filename')

Comment: Закрывающая скобка пропущена.

Comment: Спасибо, заработался